# parrot os Unable to locate /install php package 8.1

Tags: linux, repository, php-8.1, parrot-os

I have been trying to install PHP 8+ on my [Parrot 5.0](https://www.parrotsec.org/blog/2022-03-24-parrot-5.0-press-release/) but nothing works.

I tried following [Instructions on Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-php-8-1-and-set-up-a-local-development-environment-on-ubuntu-22-04)

I also tried running and adding the repo `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php` but it gives me this error described in [this issue](https://github.com/anbox/anbox-modules/issues/99)

Currently, there seems to be no solution on the net. Anyone to help?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but here is how I solved it:

Enable/Add the Sury repository:

```
    sudo apt-get update

    sudo apt-get -y install lsb-release ca-certificates curl

    sudo curl -sSLo /usr/share/keyrings/deb.sury.org-php.gpg https://packages.sury.org/php/apt.gpg
```

> make some tweaks to the next command so it can work on Parrot OS
> version 5 which is based on Debian 11 'bullseye',

```
# change this line
   # sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/deb.sury.org-php.gpg] https://packages.sury.org/php/ $(lsb_release -sc) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list'

#to this
    sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/deb.sury.org-php.gpg] https://packages.sury.org/php bullseye main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list'

    sudo apt-get update
```

I used **aptitude** for the installation so I can the handle the **ummet dependencies** error.( I got **libpcre2-8-0** error in my case).

Install aptitude:

```
sudo apt install aptitude
```

install php and it's dependencies:

```
sudo aptitude install php8.2 libapache2-mod-php8.2 php8.2-cli
```

I picked a suitable option from the solutions **aptitude** suggested.

> use **y** to select an option and **n** to go to the next available option if
> the first did not solve it (my first option was- not to install the
> packages that depended on the **libpcre2-8-0**)

Because the **OS** has a default **php** already installed, I ran:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config php
```

and selected the number of the newer version of **php** from the numbered options (it was numbered 3 in my case).

I hope this solves your problem. Let me know it if you encounter any issues while following the above steps.

For reference, Check [**the ReadMe on Sury's official repo**](https://packages.sury.org/php/README.txt).